# Call openParentApplication the second time without calling reply for the first one

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I call `openParentApplication` method in `WKInterfaceController` and in iOS waiting response from server. Then I want to cancel the operation for waiting response in iOS using `openParentApplication` again.

But the first call didn't call `reply` so the second I call `openParentApplication` it not fire the `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest`. Need to wait the timeout from the first call and then the second call will fired in `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest`.

Is there any method to cancel the first call to without wait the `reply`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/openParentApplication:reply:) confirms your problem:

> If you call this method multiple times in quick succession, your calls
>   are serialized so that each subsequent call is delayed until the
>   response from the previous call is received.

To cancel your first call, you could change a value in a shared NSUserDefaults object and check for the change in the parent applications. If changed, the first call is cancelled.

Another option is to use [Darwin notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28809226/notify-watchkit-app-of-an-update-without-the-watch-app-requesting-it/28820026#28820026) or [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole) to send a message from WatchKit to your parent application.

Comment: How to use NSUserDefault between watchkit and parent app? I can't use Group App as I have issue with Provisioning.

Comment: As I said before, I can use App Groups because I don't have provisioning in Developer Team to my project and MMWormhole is using App Groups. Is there any alternative way without using App Groups?

Comment: You may use Darwin notifications

Comment: So is there any guide or tutorial about using Darwin Notification step by step? What to code in parent App and what to code in watchkit.

Comment: Yes, I've added a link to my answer above.

Comment: Trying to following the guide you gave to me. I don't know how to write it in swift.